# How to enable QLPreviewController action buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, qlpreviewcontroller

I am working on document preview functionality. I have implemented QLPreviewController for document preview. I have successfully implemented a document preview but was not able to see the Action Button icon in the controller.

Here code of presenting controller:

```
    guard let url = URL(string: self.viewModel.attachmentPath) else { return }
    
    let quickPreviewController = PMQuickPreviewVC()
    quickPreviewController.url = url
    quickPreviewController.fileName = url.lastPathComponent
    self.show(quickPreviewController, sender: nil)
```

[image]

In the above image, buttons are not displayed but its click working properly.
I have tried many solutions but none of them are worked.

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: How are you presenting/pushing the QLPreviewController?

Comment: I used all possible way to present viewcontroller.
let quickPreviewController = PMQuickPreviewVC()
quickPreviewController.url = url
quickPreviewController.fileName = url.lastPathComponent
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: quickPreviewController)
self.show(navVC, sender: nil)

Comment: How does PMQuickPreviewVC use QLPreviewController? Is it a subclass of QLPreviewController, or does it embed it somehow? Embedding QLPreviewController inside another view controller is hard to get right. I'd suggest you push the QLPreviewController directly on your navigation stack or present it. There is also no need to create your own navigation controller to put QLPreviewController inside, QLPreviewController will create its own nav controller if needed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your barButtonItem appearance color is set to clear. try this before display document:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBlue], for: .normal)
```

Comment: Used above but not working